# Какой алгоритм использовать для решения системы с приведенной матрицей коэффициентов?

Tags: алгоритм, матрицы, численные-методы, линейная-алгебра

Какой алгоритм поиска решения (*x*<sub>1</sub>, *x*<sub>2</sub>, ...) использовать для системы с матрицей коэффициентов как на приведенной картинке?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Какие то есть свои мысли, идеи? Что то пробовали? Чем плох тот же метод гаусса или что там сейчас изучают?

Comment: @tym32167 метод Гаусса плох тем, что он неэффективен для применения к столь специализированной матрице. Здесь задача: узнать что за тип матрицы мы имеем (трехдиагональная, циклическая, симметричная, с одинаковыми коэффициентами субдиагоналей и углов) и найти литературу для решения таких систем.

Comment: Количество строк фиксированное или произвольное?

Comment: Вопрос на самом деле так себе, очень размытый. "Какой алгоритм использовать для решения системы с матрицей коэффициентов". Стоило бы в него включить больше подробностей и описания задачи и условий. Не говоря уж о том, что картинка никак не индексируется поисковиками.

Comment: @Kromster ваша правка некорректна. **Можно** использовать кучу алгоритмов. Для численных методов понятие "лучше" практически не размыто (см мой ответ). В настоящий момент (после вашей правки) на данный вопрос можно ответить: "да используй стандартную LU декомпозицию и дело с концом". Вопрос не в этом.

Comment: @AntonMenshov слово "лучше" убрано, т.к. оно не добавляет фокуса вопросу, а лишь вносит путаницу. Очевидно, что вопрос нуждается в лучшем ответе.

Comment: @Kromster не могу с вами согласиться от слова совсем.

Comment: @AntonMenshov *можно* тоже убрал, так даже *лучше*.

Comment: @Kromster с этой правкой спорить не буду, она хотя бы не вносит *путаницу*.

Comment: @AntonMenshov вы очевидо разбираетесь в вопросе. Пожалуйста, предложите к нему правку, которая его сфокусирует. Если из описания вопроса ясно, что "используй стандартную LU декомпозицию и дело с концом" субоптимальное решение, то в чем именно особенность условий в вопросе.

Comment: @Kromster Додумывать за автора детали я не буду. В данном виде на этот вопрос даны два ответа, которые на него сфокусированно отвечают. Вопрос неидеален, но достоит и имеет достаточно деталей для ответа, на мой взгляд.

Comment: @AntonMenshov *"не могу с вами согласиться от слова совсем."* Дело не в додумывании, а в дополнении описания, так чтобы вопрос лучше индексировался и его было проще найти.

Comment: @Kromster  Можно попробовать кратко описать матрицу словами. Термин трехдиагональная известен тем, кто с линейной алгеброй знаком, сталкивался со теорией сплайнов или с матфизикой. А если нет - "элементы которой вдоль главной диагонали и два угловых", или что-то подобное сообразить.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Это циклическая трёхдиагональная система ЛУ.

Её можно решить, используя прогонку для чисто трёхдиагональной матрицы и формулу Шермана-Моррисона для модификации решения.

Код можно найти в **Numerical Recipes in C,** раздел 2.7.2

Answer (score 14):

Как правильно замечено MBo, это циклическая трехдиагональная система линейных уравнений.

Есть несколько вариантов решения:

1. Использование метода прогонки (также, называется алгоритмом Томаса в англоязычной литературе) с последующим применением метода Шермана-Моррисона.
2. Так как ваша матрица симметрична, то можно работать с [Cyclic reduction](https://people.inf.ethz.ch/gander/papers/cyclic.pdf).
3. [Преобразование к треугольной системе](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/a/10139/20688). Этот дополнительный шаг будет стоить O(N), а дальше все стандартно – ибо треугольные системы решаются тривиально с конца.
4. Использование специализированных алгоритмов для циклических тридиагональных систем. Оригинальная классическая статья: [C. Temperton, "Algorithms for the solution of cyclic tridiagonal systems", *J. Comp. Phys.*, vol. 19, no. 3, pp. 317–323, Nov. 1975.](https://doi.org/10.1016/0021-9991(75)90081-9)

   Хороший обзор дается в отчете [M. Piller "On the numerical solution of cyclic tridiagonal systems"](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/357f/f840ae06c30d5d87e1e695a1936523911546.pdf). В вашем случае, матрица не просто трехдиагональная циклическая, но и с обоими субдиагоналями и "циклическими элементами" равными 1. Тут можно много подэкономить.

**Кратко о преимуществах:**

Почему использовать прогонку: простое решение и программирование.

Почему использовать другие методы: они более эффективны и могут использовать дополнительные известные свойства матрицы коэффициентов. Также они лучше когда необходимо решать системы с большим количеством правых частей.

Если задача с большим числом неизвестных и находится на критическом месте программы — то стоит инвестировать время в разработку (или подключение специализированных библиотек) наиболее эффективных методов, чтобы выжать из этого все. Такой тип матриц как в вопросе возникает невероятно часто в различных областях вычислительной физики, поэтому есть много способов, выбор которых обусловлен частностями конкретной задачи.

Answer (score -1):

Один из простых методов - метод Жордана Гаусса.  Даное уравнение решается этим методом https://matworld.ru/calculator/gauss-jordan-method-online.php, лучше применять версию не с сайта, а вариант который без обратного хода. Т.е. первая итерация - вычитание из одной строки другой домноженой на коефициент что бы елемент (1,1) стал равен еденице, и так далее. Единственная особенность этого метода - применение простых дробей. Нужно реализовать операции плюс минус умножить разделить и сократить простую дробь, завернуть этот алгоритм в несколько циклов - и ответ будет максимально точным. После получения еденичной матрицы - ответы можно переводить в десятичные дроби. Я не сравнивал эффективность метода (быстродействие), но для понимания и реализации считаю данный метод относительно не сложным. Я опробывал метод на многих уравнениях - метод вполне рабочий.

Я проверил на указанном сайте - уравнение имеет решение. Метод Жордана-Гаусса всегда решает уравнение за число итераций, которое соответствует степени уравнения. Метод хорошо считается на бумаге, алгоритм хорошо переносится на ПК. Обычно на 1-ом 2-ром втором курсе линейной алгебры оба метода Гауса изучают, а программирование методов идет после, поэтому понимание что делать облегчит задачу.

Недостатки метода Гауса:

- если на ведущей диагонали присутствуют нули, или матрица составлениа так что нет решения для даного метода, то нужно переставлять строки, и искать комбинацию порядка строк такую, что бы не было деление на ноль. Если уравнение не имеет решений вообще - то поиск решения будет очень затруднён.
- метод работает только для целых чисел или для простых дробей, любое округление приводит к тому что решение не удаётся найти
- В 1969 году Штрассен доказал, что большие матрицы можно оптимизировать перемножение более оптимально чем в методе Гаусса. Таким образом, для больших СЛАУ метод Гаусса не оптимален по скорости. Думаю 7-я степень для современных ПК - прпоблем не будет.

Comment: Метод прогонки по сути есть модификация всё того же алгоритма Гаусса, заточенная под трехдиагональные системы - а вопрос как раз о специфической матрице. Эта модификация позволяет перейти от кубической сложности Гаусса к линейной (ведь большая часть матрицы нулевая)

Comment: Метод Гауса это основа, я считаю что один из ответов обязательно должен содержать метод Гауса. Тем более что данное уравнение методом Гауса решается замечательно.

Comment: Метод Гаусса упомянут в первом же комментарии. К сожалению, задачи с подобной матрицей часто имеют размерность "over 9000", когда Гаусс уже не потянет. К тому же просто неразумно решать задачу долгим способом, когда есть быстрый и значительно более простой, заточенный именно под данный вид.

Comment: @MBo В условии не сказано 9000+. 7-мая степень для Гауса не проблема. Комментарии не считаются, т.к. в любое время они могут быть удалены админом. Так как коментариев много - в один прекрасный день их станет ноль.

Comment: Ну не знаю, какие ещё аргументы... Вот представьте, что нужно найти сумму  чисел от 1 до N. И кто-то говорит, что формулой для арифметической прогрессии пользоваться не обязательно, потому что просто сложить весь ряд - все со второго класса умеют, да и не факт, что N когда-нибудь большое понадобится.